# Rails loading assets from older gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rvm, bundler

I'm using rvm with bundler and I recently installed a new version of the bootstrap-sass gem. However, even after doing `bundle install`, Rails was still loading the old version of the bootstrap assets. Since I'm using rvm, I usually don't use `bundle exec` to run things, but I tried that as well.

It was only after I removed the old gem from my gemset (using `bundle clean --force`) that the new version of the assets started being loaded.

Here's the result of listing the gems:

```
new-host:bot palfvin$ gem list | grep bootstrap
bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.1, 2.1.0.0)
```

Here's the result of searching the Gemfile.lock file (second occurrence is from the DEPENDENCIES section):

```
new-host:bot palfvin$ grep bootstrap Gemfile.lock
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.1)
  bootstrap-sass
```

Can someone explain what was going on?

Comment: Rails needs to be restarted after gem changes ... Did you restart your Rails server after updating the gem?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server. That's what I was referring to when I was talking about the use of `bundle exec`. I usually just do `rails s`, but I tried `bundle exec rails s` just to be sure. Also, I checked that only the later version appeared in my Gemfile.lock, although both versions showed up when I did a `gem list`.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, could you post your `Gemfile` and the two different versions you see when you do `gem list`?

Comment: I no longer have the original repository or Gemfile.lock file, but I've added output from my terminal window from when they did exist.

Answer (score 0):

a little digging brought me to https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb#L43 which calls https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/lib/compass/frameworks.rb#L46-L51 - it looks like something was registering the older version of gem after it was registered in new version, check your code for calls to `register` ... just a theory.